# What is a NaN, and how do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to sum the values in the input and print them to the screen, but it returns a NaN error. Even though I type parseInt, I get a NaN error when I click on the button. Where am I making a mistake?

```
function Button() {

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    i1: "",
    i2: "",
  });

  const [result, setResult] = useState("");
  const onChangeInput = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.name;
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [event.target.name]: value,
    });
  };

  const sum = () => {
    const { i1, i2 } = input;
    const newSum = parseInt(i1) + parseInt(i2); //NaN
    setResult(newSum);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="i1" onChange={onChangeInput} /> <br />
      <input type="text" name="i2" onChange={onChangeInput} /> <br />
      <button onClick={sum}>Click</button>
      <div className="result">Result: {result} </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: I don't know precisely what is NaN, but for sure it is Not A Number 

Comment: Maybe you would want to put i1 and i2 initial values to "0" ? "" is NotANumber for sure ^^"

Comment: `const value = event.target.name;` Shouldn't that be the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `value` as `event.target.name` instead `event.target.value`:

```js
  const onChangeInput = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.name; // replace with [event.target.value]
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [event.target.name]: value,
    });
  };
```

This causes the value be a simple string and not a numeric string as you were expecting when making the sum. So the `parseInt` returns a value indicating you're trying to convert something is **not a number** (NaN).

Answer (score 1):

`const value = event.target.name;`

You're setting your value to be the name of your input. Instead you should write:
`const value = event.target.value;`

Answer (score 0):

You've some error in the **onChangeInput** function.

Change this line

```
const value = event.target.name;
```

to this line

```
const value = event.target.value;
// or destructure the object
const {value} = event.target;
```